# Create a new Timepoint column based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, calculated-columns, data-transform

I have a dataset that has a subject ID and different timepoints for each subject. I have the data filtered on few filters and want to create a new timepoint based on the existing timepoints for the subjects. The new point should be the difference between the First visit for the subject and the current visit. How can I do this in R ?

Sample data with expected result

| ID | Original_timepoint | New_timepoint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 6 | 6 |
| A | 18 | 18 |
| A | 36 | 36 |
| B | 24 | 1 |
| B | 48 | 24 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can standardize by taking the `diff` and append 1 grouped by 'ID'.  From the input data, some of the IDs are already standardized.  So, we may use an `if/else` condition to skip those IDs

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(New_timepoint = if(first(Original_timepoint)  > 1) 
          c(1, diff(Original_timepoint)) else Original_timepoint) %>%
    ungroup
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  ID    Original_timepoint New_timepoint
  <chr>              <int>         <dbl>
1 A                      1             1
2 A                      6             6
3 A                     18            18
4 A                     36            36
5 B                     24             1
6 B                     48            24
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
Original_timepoint = c(1L, 
6L, 18L, 36L, 24L, 48L), New_timepoint = c(1L, 6L, 18L, 36L, 
1L, 24L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```